# why all the properties under sprint are not working on my yaml?

Tags: java, spring

Ive just started a fresh Spring project after a long time, and Im not sure exactly what is there that I cannot make a simple configuration work.

I started with something simple, like a DB connection, like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    host: jdbc:postgresql://localhost
    port: 54322
    database: 123
    username: abc
    password: asd
```

I only have the @`SpringBootApplication` annotation, so, Im not configuring anything manually.

However, when I run this, it fails by not finding enough DB info.

My db dependencies

```
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
```

Any idea why is this?

It works when I take `datasource` **outside** of the `spring:` tag

Comment: shouldnt the host, etc go one level deeper, below datasource?

Comment: if you check [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties) you will see that there is no `spring.datasource.host`. did you mean to use [`spring.datasource.url`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.url)?

There also is no `.platform` nor `.port`, where do you have those properties from?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> spring:
>   datasource:
>   platform: postgres
>   host: jdbc:postgresql://localhost
>   port: 54322
>   database: 123
>   username: abc
>   password: asd
> ```

You've to adjust the level for the properties.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    host: jdbc:postgresql://localhost
    port: 54322
    database: 123
    username: abc
    password: asd
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, actually, I have it that way, I didnt notice the format changed when I copied in StackOverflow, apologies for that

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are using spring boot since a long time.

The properties you reference (`.platform`) are for Spring Boot 1.x ([e.g.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#DATATSOURCE)).

But the most recent version is 2.x, the properties changed slightly.
Check the new reference documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.configuration

For postgres jdbc url check https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html.

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    # platform is auto-detected now
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54332/123
    username: abc
    password: asd
```

It does work if you move it out of the spring "tag" because Spring Boot then configures an ephermal in-memory database.